# MySql queries at certain time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm supposed to make queries from MySql database once a day and display data on the page... and this sounds like cron job - I never did this before and I'd like you opinion.

if I make query once a day, I have to save this data in a file, let's say, xml file and every time the page reloads, it has to parse data from that file.
From my point of view, it would be faster and more user friendly to make query every time the page loads, as data would be refreshed ...

Any help please ....

Thank for your answers, I'll update my answer ... I don't think the queries would be extensive: something like find the most popular categories from  articles, the most popular cites from where the author is ... three of those queries. So data pulled out from database will rely only on two tables, max three and only one will have dynamic data, other will be small ones. 
I didn't ask yet why ... because it is not available at the moment ...

Comment: Well i mean your thought about may not be taking into account the size of the data set and limitations on the db server containing the data. So how big is the data set? Have you asked why it is speced this way?

Comment: What are your requirements? Do you need to save cpu or why do you plan to store your result in a file and refresh this file only once per day? Or does the query takes so long time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the load on the server. If users are requesting this data a few times a day, then pulling the data on each request should be ok ([KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) first). However, if they are slamming the server many times and the request is slow on top of that, then you should store the data off. I would just suggest storing it to a table and just clearing the table each night on a successful reload.

Comment: in fact I was thinking to built the new table ... will be KISS and still faster

Comment: :)Glad to help. As a side note, please do not forget to mark this as an accepted answer if you feel it is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a normal query that doesn't take long to execute, there is no reason to cache the result in a file. MySQL also has caching built in, which may be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on the complexity of the query.  If the "query" is actually going through a lot of work to build a dataset, or querying a dozen different database servers, i can see only doing it once per day.

For example, if you own a chain of stores across 30 states and 5 countries, each with their own stock-levels, and you want to display local stock levels on your website, i can see only going through the trouble of doing that once per day...

If efficiency is the only concern, it should be pretty easy to estimate which is better:
Time to run Query + (Time to load xml x estimated visits) 
versus
Time to run Query x Estimated Visits